# Keep getting SIGSEGV when trying to assign a function returned unsigned value to a pointer to unsigned

Tags: c++, lodepng

I am currently dealing with a project using [lodepng](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng). However, mysterious segment fault occurs when I was trying to decode PNG files into pixels.

According to the information I got using gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.                                                            
0x000055555555fd05 in lodepng_inspect (w=0x0, h=0x4, state=0x7fffffffd8b8, in=0x7ffff7eac010 "\211PNG\r\n\032\n", insize=993556)
    at util/lodepng/lodepng.cpp:3937
3937      *w = lodepng_read32bitInt(&in[16]);
```

Then I reads code at [lodepng.cpp:3937](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng/blob/master/lodepng.cpp#L3937) and therefore replayed this phenomena with a brief c++ program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include"lodepng.cpp"

using namespace std;

int main(){
    const unsigned char c[] = {0x12,0x34,0x56,0x78};
    unsigned *w=NULL;
    *w=lodepng_read32bitInt(c);
    cout << *w << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As `lodepng_read32bitInt` (find source [here](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng/blob/master/lodepng.cpp#L320)) is not declared in the header file, I have to include the cpp file.

By running it, I got a similar error in gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00005555555688bd in main () at poc.cc:9
9               *w=lodepng_read32bitInt(c);
```

So anyone has any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Get the compiler to do the counting - Change `c[4]` to `c[]`

Comment: Where is the code for `lodepng_read32bitInt`?

Comment: @EdHeal I changed the code, however, nothing help. `lodepng_read32bitInt` comes [here](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng/blob/master/lodepng.cpp#L320).

Comment: `w` is pointing to nothing.

Comment: Please post the code into the question

Comment: The linked code is confusing you as `w` is passed as an out parameter to `unsigned lodepng_inspect(unsigned* w,.....`

Comment: If the function isn't included in the header file, there's probably a reason for that.

Comment: (1) If a function is not declared in a header file, it's not for you to use. (2) Your are not using pointers correctly and this has nothing to do with the library in question (try `*w = 42;` in your example instead of the function call).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following:

```
unsigned *w=NULL;
*w=lodepng_read32bitInt(c);
```

You are trying to assign a value to what is pointed to by a nnull pointer, this is an unsigned just make that your variable type rather than having it be a pointer. always

`unsigned w =lodepng_read32bitInt(c);going to fail in user-mode code. If the function` returns an

Comment: Good answer but it's like the last bit got cut off.

Comment: @tadman -- that's one of the possible consequences of assigning through a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

As `lodepng_read32bitInt` returns `unsigned`

Change the code to

```
unsigned w = lodepng_read32bitInt(c);
cout << w << endl;
```

*EDIT* The code from the link is

```
unsigned lodepng_read32bitInt(const unsigned char* buffer)
{
  return (unsigned)((buffer[0] << 24) | (buffer[1] << 16) | (buffer[2] << 8) | buffer[3]);
}
```

Comment: BTW - `using namespace std;` is bad practice

Comment: But in [library code](https://github.com/lvandeve/lodepng/blob/master/lodepng.cpp#L3937), it's a pointer.

Comment: @TJM you need to show HOW you use the library, I doubt it's an error in the library itself.

Comment: Please following `w` to where it is defined. There is either a `malloc` involved, `&` operator somewhere in the call stack

Comment: @TJM "But in library code, it's a pointer" yea right `unsigned CRC = lodepng_read32bitInt(&in[29]);`